# What are the effects of the "EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules" flag in the project file

Tags: roslyn, csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

During my work on a Roslyn analyzer I have received an alert from Roslyn analyzer that checks the correct usage of Roslyn API.

> RS1036: Specify analyzer banned API enforcement setting.
>
> A project containing analyzers or source generators should specify the property '<EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>'.

I tried to google what this property does but did not find any additional information. Here is the link I have already checked:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.md#rs1036-specify-analyzer-banned-api-enforcement-setting

Do you know what this flag does?

Comment: The chunk of quoted text about RS1036 has a typo: the closing tag has an extra "s". It's a nit. but those of us who copied and then pasted it into a project file wish it were correct.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the mistype, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When this property is set to `true`, a predefined set of banned symbols are used for the project. You can find the list [here (main branch)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers/Core/AnalyzerBannedSymbols.txt) or [here (permalink at the time of writing the answer)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/89c1a9dd4775efb2c55af106c23d5415d8177d5e/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers/Core/AnalyzerBannedSymbols.txt)

Check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/63290) for more details on why this decision was taken.